# Windows 10 - UWP, SymmetricAlgorithm

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I tried to implement simple program to encipher file. In my WPF project i used `using System.Security.Cryptography;` but when i decided to make Universal Windows Platform App there is no `SymmetricAlhorithm class`. I tried to add reference `System.Security.Cryptography` from .NET 4.5 and 4.5.1 but there is still no SymmetricAlhorithm class.

Could you help me? Maybe you know other library to use AES cryptography?

Comment: Have you tried googling these keywords: AES WinRT SymmetricAlgorithm?

Comment: Take a look at dev.windows.com   But that class is listed as a supported class in UWP.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.aspx

Comment: It's an abstract class. You can't create one, you can only create classes which inherit from it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the following namespaces for UWP:

[Windows.Security.Cryptography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.aspx)

[Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.aspx)

There are usage examples on the linked pages and also [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/52080335-0016-4370-889b-3afe0c0dcb7a/how-to-do-simple-aes-encryptiondecryption-in-metro?forum=winappswithcsharp).